# How to pass parameter through controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I tried to create a method in a controller which will generate `totalAmount` through parameter of url and will show the amount in view.I have a model `GetTotalAmount` which return a int value after filtering data.

```
// GET: Product
public ActionResult Index(int inOrOut=0,string startDate="",string endDate="")
{
     ViewBag.totalAmount = new ProductModel().GetTotalAmount(inOrOut,startDate,endDate);
     return View();
}
```

If I hit the following url ..........

```
http://localhost:50573/Product/index/1/2018-03-01/2018-03-31
```

It returns following error............

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

**How I will get my expected view??**

Comment: what do your routes look like? If you put your parameters in the url like this, you need to have routing for those parameters, otherwise, try querystring

Comment: Is that method in  `ProductController`? And have you configured a route for it?

Comment: And not related, but why in the world are you using `string` parameters for dates - they should be `DateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two quickest solutions:

**Solution #1** - correct url parameters format

I assume you have a default routing config in App_Start\RouteConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Based on this routing you'll need to hit a following url with

```
http://localhost:50573/Product/index/1?startdate=2018-03-01&enddate=2018-03-31
```

**Solution #2** - add new route map to config

You can still hit your contoller with a url you have given.

```
http://localhost:50573/Product/index/1/2018-03-01/2018-03-31
```

In order to do that you need to add new map to your routes, so the whole RegisterRoutes method should look like this

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Product",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{inOrOut}/{startDate}/{endDate}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", inOrOut = 0,
                startDate = "",
                endDate = ""
            }
        );
    }
```

I would recommend you to read more about routing
[HERE](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: The `defaults` in the new route does not make much sense here because if those values are not provided, it will just match the first route and it will not even make it this far. Good answer by the way.